# How to pass slug value to a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am able to access `username1/edit`in the URL but not able to do so by clicking a link in the template.

**urls.py**

`url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/edit/$', ProfileEdit.as_view(), name='profile_edit'),`

**template.html**

`<a href="{% url 'profile:profile_edit' %}">edit</a>`

i get the following error

**Reverse for 'profile_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-\w\d]+)/edit/$']**

i get the problem is not sending the slug value to the url. but how to send the slug value from a template?

Comment: As the error shows, you haven't passed the slug to the url tag.

Comment: i get that! how do i overcome the error?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the question:

`<a href="{% url 'profile:profile_edit' slug=profile.slug %}">Edit</a>`